# Is there a Zendesk plugin to fetch order information from Craft Commerce?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugins

I'm looking for the same functionality as https://wordpress.org/plugins/mwb-zendesk-woo-order-sync/ but for craftCMS's Commerce plugin and not Wordpress's Woocommerce plugin.

Basically, it would use the reporter's email from the zendesk ticket to get the order or orders from Craft Commerce and display the order information in a zendesk widget.

I've looked, and all I can find are plugins for creating tickets.

Does anyone know of an existing plugin for zendesk that does this?

Answer (score 1):

As of today (08/06/2020) there isn't a plugin that does that in the [Plugin Store](https://plugins.craftcms.com/), so you'd need to do some [custom plugin development](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/) if that's what you're looking for.